# Optional tokens in path

Tags: path-aliases, redirection

Sites such as StackExchange use URLs that contain a page code and some additional keywords, possibly for SEO. If you change anything in the additional keywords, you are still redirected to the correct long URL.

Example: the following links redirect to the same page:

- [drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/724/why-is-drupal-7-so-slow](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/724/why-is-drupal-7-so-slow)
- [drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/724/](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/724/)

As long as the page code (`/questions/724`) is in the link, it is valid. So, we can construct many links that still resolve to the same page, e.g.

- [drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/724/old-page-title](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/724/old-page-title)

This is very interesting for future-proof URLs, as the title of a page could change, but the URLs would still redirect to the correct page.

Can this be accomplished by using existing Drupal modules?

Comment: _This is very interesting for future-proof URLs_. That's what redirects are for...not a great idea to leave potentially loads of URLs out there all resolving to the same page. Yes you can save yourself SEO penalty with a canonical tag, but I wouldn't call it desirable necessarily. That said, you could almost certainly set something like this up using `hook_url_inbound_alter()` and/or `hook_url_outbound_alter()` (both part of core)

Comment: I'm not looking for redirects. You say the URL scheme I described is "not a great idea" but many large sites use it, lifehacker.com is another one. Surely it must make sense if they can pull it off without penalties. As for the `hook_url_inbound_alter()`, I imagine this is possible, but I'm looking for a solution based on existing modules only at this point.

Comment: Ah right - I wouldn't have thought there's an existing module for something quite to specific, but you never know with Drupal. Just want to check that you understand that redirecting is _exactly_ what Amazon are doing here (as per best practice)? If you visit the first URL above, it 301 redirects to the 2nd URL. That's what I mean by redirecting - there's no decent solution to this that _won't_ involve a redirect. All you're essentially looking for is a second set of URL aliases to be valid for your nodes, and for those aliases to forward onto the short URL version

Comment: On second thought, redirects may be okay. I noticed stackexchange does it better: you can change the keywords in the url and it redirects to the correct url. Do you know how to implement this? I will edit the question.

Comment: By the way, you got a redirect on the first link since StackExchange actually changes Amazon links it recognizes. If the link is literal, you don't get a redirect. You can check it on the revisions page http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/117764/revisions

Comment: "All you're essentially looking for is a second set of URL aliases to be valid for your nodes, and for those aliases to forward onto the short URL version". Almost: I'd like the same behavior as StackeExchange: I'd like the aliases to redirect to the official long URL.

Comment: Ok, I rewrote the question. You convinced me that redirects may indeed be a good solution.